# How to use the filter to return all the values based on what date I choose on my datepicker using React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi developers I have problem regarding filtering the data based on the date that I used on the date picker currently using react js. the filtering working well if the input date is less than to the date I search. to understand well I will make a snippet sample code.

if you run this code on the console the only value that I get is the 2021-02-12, however my condition on my filter is less than equal to my input. so probably the expected output is 2021-02-12 and 2021-03-21.

So the big question: Why this condition not met?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<script>
  const data = 
  [{id: 1, receive_date: "2021-02-12", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 2, receive_date: "2021-03-22", remarks: "14"},
  {id: 3, receive_date: "2021-03-20", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 4, receive_date: "2021-03-21", remarks: "15"}];

  const input = 'March 20, 2021';
  const inputTS = new Date(input).getTime();
  const result = data.filter(d=>Date.parse(d.receive_date) <= inputTS);

  console.log(result);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same method you're using to create a timestamp in both areas: where you're turning the `input` into a timestamp, and where you're turning each `receive_date` into a timestamp, to ensure consistency:

```js
const data = 
  [{id: 1, receive_date: "2021-02-12", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 2, receive_date: "2021-03-22", remarks: "14"},
  {id: 3, receive_date: "2021-03-20", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 4, receive_date: "2021-03-21", remarks: "15"}];

const input = 'March 20, 2021';
const inputTS = new Date(input).getTime();
const result = data.filter(d=>new Date(d.receive_date).getTime() <= inputTS);

console.log(result);
```

or

```js
const data = 
  [{id: 1, receive_date: "2021-02-12", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 2, receive_date: "2021-03-22", remarks: "14"},
  {id: 3, receive_date: "2021-03-20", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 4, receive_date: "2021-03-21", remarks: "15"}];

const input = 'March 20, 2021';
const inputTS = Date.parse(input);
const result = data.filter(d=> Date.parse(d.receive_date) <= inputTS);

console.log(result);
```

But since the `input` string isn't one of the standard formats, it'd be better to either turn it into one of the standard formats first, eg `2020-3-20` - or pass the year / month index / day to the constructor:

```js
const data = 
  [{id: 1, receive_date: "2021-02-12", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 2, receive_date: "2021-03-22", remarks: "14"},
  {id: 3, receive_date: "2021-03-20", remarks: "11"},
  {id: 4, receive_date: "2021-03-21", remarks: "15"}];

const input = '2021-3-20';
const inputTS = new Date(input).getTime();
const result = data.filter(d=> Date.parse(d.receive_date) <= inputTS);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hi why if I use the data.filter(d=> Date.parse(d.receive_date) <= inputTS); the data is not showing on my table. but it on my console has data?